# Updating two UILabels concurrently

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading

I have two UILabels that require updating on millisecond basis. I ran my app and noticed that one of the UILabels ("The Second UILabel") updates slower than the first one. It's not a large difference but it's perceptible.

The Second UILabel does a short computation before displaying its results on the UILabel. I suspect I may need to push this to a background thread.

I have used threads in Java but would like to explore GCD, operations queue, dispatch queue, etc. I've read a lot on them (especially from Apple website) but just can't make sense of them.

So I need to check with the gurus here:

Q1: Is The Second UILabel perception problem due to updating of the UI Thread that lead to thread contention?

Q2: Does my app updating The Second UILabel require a background thread or will GCD and the like suffice?

Comment: You should update UI only from the main thread. In case you are doing any background computations, make sure to wrap your UI code in a block and dispatch it on the main queue.

Comment: Would you have sample code to show?

Comment: You provided a valid answer down below :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer.

```
dispatch_queue_t background_queue = dispatch_queue_create("label", NULL);

dispatch_async(background_queue, ^{
    // do some stuff that takes a long time here...

    // follow up with some stuff on the main queue
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // Typically updating the UI on the main thread.

    });
});
```